# Passing vector of unique_ptr with move semantics in c++

Tags: c++, stdvector, unique-ptr, stdmove

I am learning CPP++14 move semantics.While writing a small code I observed some weird behavior. I am moving vector of unique ptr to a function using r-value refrence.  on debuuging I found that the changes are being applied to the moved object also. Why am I observing this hcnage even the object is moved? Whats does the move do in following code?

```
void func(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> && vect) {
    vect.emplace_back(std::move(std::make_unique<int>(3)));
    return ;
}

int  main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> a;
    func(std::move(a));
    cout<<(*(a[0]))<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not moving anything. You are just passing the object by rvalue reference. The move is no more then a cast in your code.

Comment: @super Don't answer in comments please if the quesiton is useful and _on-topic_.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics) should help your understanding of move semantics.  You also might want to consider getting yourself a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - if you write a short answer it gets automatically converted to a comment.

Comment: @Den-Jason Ah ty. I didn't know that. Must have been changed recently. I was a year off to the meta boot camp ;-)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If it happens, it's not automatic. Could be reviews or mods.

Answer (score 5):

> Whats does the move do in following code?

Move operation is not performed in `func(std::move(a));` in fact, [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) just performs conversion and produces an rvalue (xvalue) expression, which is just bound to the rvalue reference parameter `vect` of `func`. Then any modification on `vect` inside `func` has effect on the argument (i.e. `a`) too, they refer to the same object.

> In particular, `std::move` produces an xvalue expression that identifies its argument `t`. It is exactly equivalent to a `static_cast` to an rvalue reference type.

If you change the parameter to pass-by-value, then you'll see move operation is performed. And given the usage you showed, just pass-by-lvalue-reference seems less confusing (and no need to use `std::move` on argument again).

BTW: In `vect.emplace_back(std::move(std::make_unique<int>(3)));` the usage of `std::move` is superfluous, `std::make_unique<int>(3)` been an rvalue expression.

Comment: It converts it to an rvalue reference, not an rvalue.  All reference types are lvalues.

Comment: @NathanOliver value category is a property of expressions, not types. `move(a)` as an expression is an rvalue.

Comment: Can this be considered as good practice to use this approach ? Will this create any memory related issues like cleaning memory and leakages?

Comment: @asheeshkumarsinghal Your code is fine for the usage you showed; it's just confusing. Just pass-by-lvalue-reference seems better here.

Comment: ok. L value ref also gives the same result. However, Since its contains unique pointers shouldn't "a" be moved?

Comment: @asheeshkumarsinghal If you take the vector by value it will be moved. Passing something by reference will not move it. A reference is just something that refers to the original.

Comment: @asheeshkumarsinghal No, it has nothing to do with what `a` is for this case. It's just bound to the reference parameter. If you create a new object which is copied from an rvalue, move operation happens.

Comment: Ah! Understood. And Since 'vect' is simply a reference to 'a', it will have no effect on its lifetime. Also 'vect' get destroyed/ freed as soon as function completes its execution. Am I correct?

Comment: @asheeshkumarsinghal Yes it's just a reference, and get destroyed when get out of the function. Note that the object referenced by it (i.e. `a`) doesn't get destroyed.